# Can't define an unary operator for a tuple

Tags: operators, swift, unary-operator

It appears that you can't define an unary operator for a tuple. Consider this example:

```
@prefix func - (tuple: (Int, Int)) -> (Int, Int) {
    return (-tuple.0, -tuple.1)
}

let t = (1, 2)
-t
```

And I get an error: *could not find an overload for '-' that accepts the supplied arguments*. Is this an expected behavior?

It's worth noting that binary operators work fine, e.g. you can define `==` for tuples and it works as expected.

Comment: This does not even work in Swift 4.2 for me. I am not able to create a prefix unary operator '-' for my Tuple with 4 items. Were you able to find a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

I've been playing around with this and it looks like a bug to me. There's nothing wrong with the code in your function and it should work as a prefix. You can file a bug report [here](https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/). You could also try to post this in the Apple Developer forums and you might get a reply from an official source.

Comment: Yeah, I've filed a few Swift bug reports already, and this seems like a good candidate for another one, just wanted to clarify it. I've made a topic on the Developer forums too, probably should wait a couple of days for the response before reporting it.

Comment: How can the compiler tell the difference between defining a unary operator for a tuple of Ints, and defining a binary operator for Int?

Comment: Well, why not? The syntax is different. You can also use a typealias: `typealias IntPair = (Int, Int)`, but it still doesn't work as expected.

Comment: @Nicky: how is it different?

Comment: @newacct: it would be `@infix func - (lhs: Int, rhs: Int) -> ...` for a pair of Ints. Did I miss you point, perhaps?

Comment: @Nicky: But the two are the same. You are just binding variables in the elements of the tuple in one case and the entire tuple in the other case.

Comment: @Nicky: The only difference seems to be the `@infix` versus `@prefix` or `@postfix`.

Comment: @newacct, with a tuple you have a function with one argument, with two ints you have a function with two arguments. Despite being a tuple, it still counts for one argument, not two.

Comment: @Nicky: But a function of "two arguments" *is* a function of one argument which is a tuple. The type is `(Int, Int) -> ...` where the `(Int, Int)` part means a tuple. You can pass a tuple to a function expecting two arguments, and you can pass two arguments to a function expecting a tuple. Any irregularities are bugs.

Comment: @newacct: this is true that you can pass a tuple to a function expecting two arguments, but not vice versa. If you pass two arguments to a function expecting a tuple, you'll get "Extra argument in call" error.

Comment: @Nicky: If you pass variables instead of numeric constants, then it works. I believe the issue with constants is a compiler bug or overloading ambiguity.

Comment: @newacct: Oh, indeed. This is interesting! Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick workaround:

```
/// Should've called "Double"
/// but it is already taken for double-precision number
struct Duple<L,R> {
    let l:L
    let r:R
    init(_ l:L, _ r:R) {
        self.l = l
        self.r = r
    }
    @conversion func __conversion()->(L,R) {
        return (l, r)
    }
}
@prefix func -<L:SignedNumber, R:SignedNumber>
    (d:Duple<L,R>)->Duple<L,R> {
    return Duple(-d.l, -d.r)
}

let pair = Duple(4, -2)
let (left, right) = -pair
println("\(left,right)")
```

Written with generics so it works not only for (Int, Int) but also any 2-element tuples which conforms to the SignedNumber protocol.

Comment: This is pretty cool, even though I'd personally refrain from using undocumented internals. I hope they make it public in one way or another.

Comment: @Nicky It seems to me that a lot of stuff is undocumented at the moment that will obviously be documented at some point in the future.  I wouldn't worry about it unless it is not documented in release 1.